# Absolute beginner needing some help with PostgreSQL and Python

Tags: postgresql, database-design, python

I am primarily a developer, with very little experience around databases, and this is my first time using PostgreSQL. I am using Python 3.6 and PostgreSQL with Psycopg2.

After a user enters a **membership_number**, 3 things should happen:

1. Save the **membership_number** with the **time and date**, and the **location** of the store, in a table, let's say the *search
   table*.
2. Retrieve the **customer_name** associated with that **membership_number**, if it is already in the *users' table*.
3. If **customer_name** is not present, ask the user for it and save it on the *users' table*.

Both tables have the **customer_id** so I can cross check *all the times* that someone has searched for a particular **membership_number**, get their name and  other records with a `LEFT JOIN`.

I plan to have several devices linked to it, so my main concern is *race conditions* if I write a query that does something like this:

- check if **membership number** is present, if not, ask the user for the **customer_name**, then save it and then retrieve the fields needed and make some left join to get aditional info.

Even if this is the right way to do it, I don't get how that query would be constructed.

Also, I've read something about temp tables, but should I:

- send the membership_number
- save to a temp table
- update search table
- return results if present in users' table
- if not, ask store for customer_name
- save to temp table
- update users' table
- return results (from left join)

This doesn't seem right.

Also read something about `IF NOT EXISTS`, but again, never used it and don't know how to.

Could it possibly be done with just one table? Am I overthinking this? What should be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## DATABASE

The primary function of a database is to ensure that you always have valid data.

Defining `valid data` is done with `CONSTRAINTS` (including NOT NULL) and Data Types.

Your application design seems to be based on the idea: "a database is a `bit bucket` to store data".

This isn't how you treat a database.

A lot of your requirements can be handled by the database if and only if you properly define what is `valid data`.

Your applications should:
 1. Try to modify the data.
 2.  If the modification fails, handle it within your application.

## Constraints

Here is how `constraints` can throw an error for your application to handle your specified situations.

### Adding row to `Search` table (scan entry)

After you type in the membership ID, you attempt to `INSERT` a row into the `Search` table.

The `Foreign Key Constraint` will automagically lookup the `membership_id` in the `User's` table.  If the `membership_id` is not found, the `INSERT` throws an error.

### Adding row to User's Table (membership info)

After you ask for the person's name for the given `membership_id`, you attempt to `INSERT` a row into the `User's` table.

A `Primary Key Constraint` will ensure that one row and only one row exists in the `User's` table with that `membership_id`.

If that `membership_id` already exists, an error is thrown for your `INSERT` statement.

### Updating User's information

You are going through a "update customer info" set of pages.  You attempt to `UPDATE` a row in the `User's` table.

If that `membership_id` does not exists, an error is thrown for your `UPDATE` statement.

### If row exists, UPDATE; if not, INSERT

Some databases have a `MERGE` or `UPSERT` statement that allows you to `UPDATE` a row.  If it doesn't exist, it will `INSERT` the row.

### Lookup Member's Name from User's Table (membership info)

You `SELECT` some data from the `Users` table.

I'm not 100% sure if you'll receive a "no data found" error for this one.

However, you can always check if you have received 0, 1, or more rows within your application.

### Race Condition

A lot of your "Race Condition" concerns should be handled by an [ACID Compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) database (eg PostgreSQL)

Comment: Thanks Randolph for the edit. Michael: pretty sure this is gold for me, thanks a lot. It gave me a lot of direction towards understanding db and tables. Have been reading about these topics you mentioned and will continue doing so. You guys rock. Will mark as answered even when I have so much to learn, but this is the right path, thanks again for pointing it out.